# How to disable a label with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I disable a label with jQuery? I tried:

`$('#some-id').prop('disabled', true);`

but it's not grayed out.

My HTML is: `<label for="some-id">Label Here</label><input id="some-id"/>`

Comment: You have to set a css rule to grey out the label

Comment: Already asked on stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330541/how-can-i-change-a-labels-color-when-its-input-is-disabled

Comment: Label will not change colour automatically when you disable it.  You need to define a corresponding class in your CSS.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`labels` do not have a disable property inherently built in.  You will need to add a class to disable them yourself.

Something like:

```
.disabled {
   color: darkgrey;
   background-color: grey;
}
```

And to add the class to your element:

```
$('#some-id').addClass('disabled');
```

Answer (score 6):

To disable a label, disable the form control it is associated with.

That won't change the appearance of the label though, for that you have to change the CSS that applies to it. That is best done by adding (or removing) a class from the element (and having a pre-existing CSS ruleset that matches that class).

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one, IMO. Accepted answer only makes it look disabled whereas this suggests to disable the input that the label controls and also makes it appear disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable an input like this:

```
$("#test").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

It should be noted that you can't disable a label, as it doesn't accept any input to begin with. If you want it to *look* disabled, you might consider just changing the color of the text to gray.

```
$("#test").css("color", "#666");
```

Comment: That downvote was before your edit, and was probably because you can't disable a label using `.attr()` or anything else

Answer (score 0):

You should add a disabled class to the label when you disable the input. You could do it like this if you want to keep all the code in the same place:

```
$('#some-id, [for="some-id"]').prop('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
```

Working [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisLTD/exFvw/).