# Is there a .NET Framework control for buttons that look and behave like control panel links?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Can I use one of these link-like buttons in a WinForms app (e.g. "Control Panel Home", "Add a Device" etc. see pic)?

In Windows 7+ settings they are everywhere. I wonder that must be a common control? If you hover over them they are highlighted and underlined. You click on them you fire an event etc. `LinkLabel` behaves differently and I can't find `LinkButton` in .NET.

[image]

Comment: Which exactly control do you need? There are several different on the picture. "Text which you click" is basically any control able to display text + [`Click`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: @Sinatr Let's say one with the least extra work.

Comment: Have a look at [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17524999/1997232) and tell what it lacks.

Comment: @Sinatr It lacks hover over highlighting.

Comment: @Bitterblue Use a [LinkLabel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel(v=vs.110).aspx)?!

Comment: What effect do you want for highlighting? Highlighting is made by handling  `MouseEnter` + `MouseLeave` events, but depends on what should happens with control the solution will vary.

Comment: @Sinatr The very same as in Windows Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `LinkLabel` control is what you want.

To get it to behave like the Control Panel, set it's `LinkBehavior` property to `HoverUnderline`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [DotNetBars](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/) and choice controls best for you.