# Clickable Label for Checkbox GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt

## In HTML this is quite easy

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" value="value" />
<label for="checkbox_id">Text</label>
```

[Code from] [How to create an HTML checkbox with a clickable label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-an-html-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label)

## Not sure how it's done in GWT

My issue is I'm not sure how to replicate this in **GWT** with their native checkbox.  This is a snippet from my `ui.xml` file inside an `<HTMLPanel>`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" ui:field="defaultCheckBoxText">Checkbox Label</td>
        <td><g:CheckBox ui:field="defaultCheckBox"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The way the layout is, I need to keep with the table so **I can't use the label around the input** technique.  I mean, I can, but I would prefer to know how to do it the other way.

---

## I've tried this, but it didn't work

The reason being, in the compiled GWT code, the actual ID of the element is **gwt-uid-1118**.  I could change the label to `<label for="gwt-uid-1118">`, but that is not a good idea since they are dynamically generated.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" ui:field="defaultCheckBoxText"><label for="defaultCheckBox">Checkbox Label</label></td>
        <td><g:CheckBox ui:field="defaultCheckBox"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

## TL;DR

Anybody know how a clickable label (separate from the `CheckBox`) in GWT is done in the ui.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I tested two ways to do this. In both cases, you would leave your CheckBox's label empty (no text in the `label` tag).

**Option 1:** You use a `<g:CheckBox>` and a `<g:Label>` (which creates a div) and you use that `<g:Label>` to mimic the Checkbox's label.

**In your ui.xml**

```
<td>
    <g:Label ui:field="lbl">The Label</g:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <g:CheckBox ui:field="chk" />
</td>
```

**In your java class:**

```
@UiField Label lbl;
@UiField CheckBox chk;

//put this handler in the constructor
lbl.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            chk.setValue(!chk.getValue(), true);
            //This will so it will manually operate the checkbox
        }
    });
```

---

**Option 2:** You use a HTML `<label>` instead of a GWT `<g:Label>` and give it the same ID as the Checkbox, so it becomes a secondary label (hacky).

**In your ui.xml**

```
<td>
    <label ui:field="lbll">The Label</label>
</td>
<td>
    <g:CheckBox ui:field="chk" />
</td>
```

**In your java class:**

```
@UiField CheckBox chk;
@UiField LabelElement lbll;

@Override
protected void onLoad() {
    super.onLoad();
    //This part has to happen onLoad, which is where a unique ID gets generated

    //Get the g:Checkbox's ID
    String uniqueID = chk.getElement().getFirstChildElement().getId();

    //set it to the html label
    lbll.setAttribute("for", uniqueID);
    //now the g:CheckBox has 2 labels, one of them being yours
    //and the other one being the one it comes with
}
```

**EDIT:** Come to think of it, Option 1 is a better choice since it gives you a `ClickHandler`, and that's what you wanted. It's also less hacky.

Answer (score 3):

Try `text` attribute:

```
<g:CheckBox ui:field="checkbox" text="text"/>
```

**EDIT.** If you have a strict html structure then you need to use low level GWT components like `InputElement`:

Updated UiBinder:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="defaultCheckBox">Checkbox Label</label></td>
        <td><input ui:field="defaultCheckBox" id="defaultCheckBox" type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Corresponding java binding:

`@UiField InputElement defaultCheckBox;`

Comment: Normally `text` would be a fantastic solution! Unfortunately, I have to have the label and the check-box separate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to separate the actual checkbox from a descriptive label for a checkbox then here is one way you can accomplish it using GWT widgets:

**ui.xml snippet:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">
      <g:HTML text="Checkbox Label" ui:field="defaultCheckBoxText"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <g:CheckBox ui:field="defaultCheckBox"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**java code:**

```
HTML defaultCheckBoxText;
CheckBox defaultCheckbox;

.....

UiHandler("defaultCheckBoxText")
protected void onCheckboxLabelClick(ClickEvent event) {

    // whether you want change handler to be fired on checkbox (optional)
    boolean fireevent = false; 

    // toggle the checked value
    defaultCheckbox.setValue(!defaultCheckbox.getValue(), firevent);
}
```

If you don't want to use "GWT Widgets" then @Maksym Demidas answer is the alternative using pure DOM. Remember that you can use the 'ui:field' notation on DOM elements as well to hook them back into your java code. "LabelElement" is the java equivalent to "<label/>" in your binder file. The LabelElement#htmlFor is how you access the html "for=''".

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`ensureDebugId(String id)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html) over your `CheckBox`. This ends up setting the `for` attribute of the label element. Look at the source.
When in doubt just check the [Showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox) and/or the JavaDoc.

In `UiBinder` you can use the relative `debugId="id"`.

Also, check out this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4667) (and the attached workaround) that seems quite related if you rely on the event propagation of the click over the label (and not just over the input elment).