# Change text next to checkbox IF checked. HTML + JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I just want to use a simple checkbox, for example, a checkbox with 'Please check this' next to it, then when it's clicked the text changes to 'Checked'

I've been looking all over for a simple solution, but struggling and can't figure it out - despite the simplicity.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: what language u are using ?

Comment: In what language? Is this a web page, an application, a spreadsheet, etc.?

Comment: Sorry! Using HTML + JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#boxid').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).siblings('label').html('checked');
  } else {
    $(this).siblings('label').html(' not checked');
  }
});
```

and in your HTML:

```
<input id="boxid" type="checkbox"><label for="boxid">not checked</label>
```

**EDIT:**

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zpzxM/

Comment: Thank you! Tired eyes couldn't figure this out! So simple!

Comment: @50dollanote you'r welcome **Important** I just used .click so this doesn't work if the user check the box using keyboard, you can use .change etc.

Comment: @50dollanote well checked the fiddle and it also works when I use keyboard! strange!

Comment: I think this is the answer he's looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-an-html-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript:**

```
function changeText(id){

  if ($('#'+id).is(':checked')) {
    $('#'+id +"+span").html('Checked');
  }else{
    $('#'+id+ "+span").html('Please check this.');
  }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="123" onclick="changeText(this.id);"><span>Please check this.</span>
```

["live Example"](http://jsbin.com/iRafIQo/14/edit)

Comment: You can also use ~ instead of + in the selector. That will also give you the same result. But for your case use of + is favorable as you only want to edit the adjacent sibling only.