# move_uploaded_file does not work

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have tried different metods for file upload system. None of them worked so far, I know that there are lots of similar questions, I checked and tried nearly all of them yet they did not work.

It gives the last echo if I try to upload files. If the files is more than the max size than it gives the wrong echo "Sorry, this filetype is not allowed"

**Here is my php code**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($FileType == "exe" && $FileType == "dll" && $FileType == "zip"  ) {
    echo "Sorry, this filetype is not allowed";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo " <br>Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

**Here is the HTML Code**

```
<html>
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css"></head>
<title>Dosya Yükleme</title>
<body>

<form action="fileupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Bir dosya seçiniz:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Yükle">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I simplified code, putting both php and html in same php file and erasing the checking process.

**New PHP file which still doesn't work**

```
 <?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?> 

<html>
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css"></head>
<title>Dosya Yükleme</title>
<body>

<form action="fileupload.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Bir dosya seçiniz:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Solution chmod -R 777

Comment: I found them all nothing seems to be different but solutions did not work on it. If you found an aswer that can really solve it please send me the link.

Comment: The dublicate tag was unnecessary since the solution was unrelated. I found the solution on ubuntu forum. The problem was file permission. Once there was a post about file permission but the code was wrong. On that topic the terminal code was chmod 0751 -R folder but the working code is chmod -R 777 folder

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, instead of editing it into the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on ubuntu forum. The problem was file permission. Once there was a post about file permission but the code was wrong. On that topic the terminal code was **chmod 0751 -R *folder*** but the working code is 
**chmod -R 777 *folder***

Comment: Closed as not reproducible to the extent that others will not have the same setup. That said, it is useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

Change `&&` to `||` in the type conditional branch:

```
if($FileType == "exe" || $FileType == "dll" || $FileType == "zip"  ) {
```

Comment: Thanks but it still did not work.. at least we got rid of the second error I guess. But more importantly it still doesn't upload the file

Comment: Do debugging: Add `var_dump($variable)` in your code for every variable that is being used, and compare the contents of the variable with your assumption.

Comment: The dublicate tag was unnecessary since the solution was unrelated. I found the solution on ubuntu forum. The problem was file permission. Once there was a post about file permission but the code was wrong. On that topic the terminal code was chmod 0751 -R folder but the working code is chmod -R 777 folder

Answer (score 0):

I think an issue is with the submit button and trying to check its value with `if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {`. It seems that the name of the button needs to be `submit`.

Have a look at [Send value of submit button when form gets posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579616/send-value-of-submit-button-when-form-gets-posted).

Comment: I don't see how `$_POST['upload']` is going to work if you change the name attribute to `'submit'`.