# Image button is not working but normal buttons are working: php

Tags: php, html, forms, imagebutton

I wrote a code it is like a todolist, before it was working, but right now normal buttons are working but the type image buttons are not working.
What is wrong with it?

Up part:

```
if (isset($_POST['remove_list'])){
    echo("xxx");
$todo_id = $_POST['remove_list'];   //get that submit value.
$sql="DELETE FROM todo WHERE todo_id='$todo_id'"; //that users book
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}

if (isset($_POST['add_list'])){
    echo("yyy");
    $todo_text=$_POST['text'];
    $sql = "insert into todo(todo_text) values('$todo_text')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
}
```

Bottom form part:

```
<form form method="post" action="admin.php?id=anasayfa">
    <table>
        
    <?php 
        
    $todosql="SELECT * from todo";
    $resulttodo= mysqli_query($conn, $todosql);
    $i=1; 
    while ($todo=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulttodo)){


    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <?php if ($todo['todo_checked']==1){ ?>
        <input type="image" src="images/admin/checked.png" border="0" alt="Submit" name="not_check" height="20"  value="<?php echo($todo['todo_id']);?>">
    <?php
    }
    else { ?>
        <input type="image" src="images/admin/success.png" border="0" alt="Submit" name="check" height="20"  value="<?php echo($todo['todo_id']);?>">
    <?php
    }
    ?>         
    </td> 
    <td><?php echo($todo['todo_text']); ?></td><td><input type="image" src="images/admin/cancel.png" border="0" alt="Submit" name="remove_list" height="20" value="<?php echo($todo['todo_id']);?>"></td>
    </tr>
        
        
    <?php } ?>  
        
    </table>
    <input type="text" name="text" >
<input type="submit" name="add_list" value="Ekle">
</form>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: which image dont show?

Comment: the php action is not working @dean

Comment: the php has a `$_GET['id']` try to validate your form  by the get value.

Comment: the input type isn't an image, looks like a boolean/radio from looking at your code.. (checked/unchecked)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: Also, be warned that your code is vulnerable for SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please consider securing your upload code :

- `$sql="DELETE FROM todo WHERE todo_id='$todo_id'";` is not secure...
- See http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php
- You'd rather use prepared statement or other MySQL escaping method.

Next, you're using `input type="image"` along with `input type="submit"`. Since `input type="image"` also submit the form, please use only one submit button.

Also `value="<?php echo($todo['todo_id']);?>"`is useless since value of image buttons do not accept value attributes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image

And first of all, submit button name are never send, so `if (isset($_POST['add_list']))` will always return false. See [Send value of submit button when form gets posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579616/send-value-of-submit-button-when-form-gets-posted)