# Why does my page not update after the button being pressed? Flask

Tags: python, forms, flask

When I press either of these `<input>`'s, the `Led` does not get updated on the page.

.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
default_val = True


@app.route('/switch_led', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def led_handler():
    on = request.form.get('ON', default_val)
    off = request.form.get('OFF', default_val)
    if on:
        Led = 'ON'
    elif off:
        Led = 'Not ON'
    return render_template('index.html', Led=Led)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ Led }}</h1>
    <form action="/switch_led" method="POST">
        <p><input type="submit" name="btnled" value="ON"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="btnled" value="OFF"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely:

```
default_val = True # this is important!
...

on = request.form.get('ON', default_val)
off = request.form.get('OFF', default_val)
if on:
    Led = 'ON'
```

So, when you click the OFF button, `form.get('ON', default_val)` will fail to find the ON toggle and return the default instead... which equals `True`!

The first condition you check is `if on:`, but, according to the logic above `on` is *always* `True`, so your LED will always stay ON. The `elif` condition doesn’t matter because the first one is always satisfied.

Comment: When I remove `default_val`, I get an UnboundLocalError saying:
local variable 'Led' referenced before assignment. So the whole HTML page won't load.

Comment: @5824, there’s also a flaw in your HTML, which can be fixed [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579616/send-value-of-submit-button-when-form-gets-posted).

Comment: could you explain, I do have the `name`s the same for both buttons

Comment: @5824, you do, but you’re trying to get the values of the _names_ ON and OFF, which don’t exist. You should pass the individual (unique!) names of your buttons to `request.form.get`.