# HTML form is not submitting or doing any actions when button submit clicked

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that has one hidden input field, the hidden field includes the value of email.
the problem when the button clicked, the form didn't submit any values at all and nothing happens at all.

the HTML form as shown below:

```
         <form method="post" class="table-responsive" action="alerts.php">
            <?php foreach ($admins as $key => $admin): ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $admin['email']; ?>">
            <?php endforeach;?>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg btn-block  add"
                name="e_conf">confirm</button>

        </form>
```

i  tried to test if the form submit the values or not but set output message in the server side:

```
if(isset($_POST["e_conf"])){
echo "test";
}
```

but nothing displayed at all which I understood that the form didn't submit any values.
I hope someone can figure out this problem
thanks

Comment: Did you try ```<input type="submit">``` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send value of submit button when form gets posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579616/send-value-of-submit-button-when-form-gets-posted)

Comment: Please check and make sure javascript code is not blocking your form submission.

Comment: @AnisurRahman I tried it doesn't work

Comment: @OskarGrosser I checked it out still not working for me

Comment: @Sachin may I know how to check that coz in counsel no error produced

Comment: Is there any javascript code in your page i.e. code inside <script> tag.

Comment: @Sachin yes i have these 
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>`
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>`
    `<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        CKEDITOR.replace('body_en');
        CKEDITOR.replace('body_ar');


    });
    </script>`

Comment: @Sachin i have disabled all this scripts and also chrome extensions but still same problem

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below jquery code to submit form, Make sure jquery is included in your project.

```
<script>
$(".add").click(function(){
    $(".table-responsive").submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: same problem it doesn't work, I tried to `echo $_POST["email"]` in same page and it worked and display the value without submitting the button. *the server page is included in the main page though*