# get id from buttons with same name in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, button

So I have a website that runs a cycle on a database as long as there is a record in it.
It also puts two buttons in each row within the table.
Each button has the same name.
If I press one of the buttons, how can I get the ID of that button (which points to a Youtube link from the database) to be included in a SQL query.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ruben MediaShare</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method='POST'>
<?php

session_start(); 

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['modname'] . "!";
} else {
    echo "Please log in first to see this page.";
}


$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "asd", "asd", "mediareq");
 
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM requests";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>link</th>";
                echo "<th>Twitch Név</th>";
                echo "<th>Üzenet</th>";
                echo "<th>Engedélyezés</th>";
                echo "<th>Elutasítás</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            $link = $row['link'];
                echo "<td>" . "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='$link' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>" . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['ttvname'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['msg'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' id='$link' value='' name='enable'></input>" . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' id='$link' value='' name='eject'></input>" . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        if (isset($_POST['enable'])) {
            $ID = $_POST[$link];
            echo $ID;
        }
    } else{
        echo "Még nem kaptál videót, várjál már egy kicsit vagy csak tolj egy F5öt Pog Pog Pog";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The website looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYUQt.jpg

If it can't be done that way, what can I do in this case to keep the loop but since it has to be dynamic, and somehow get it to pick the link from each button that it stores in the ID (or some other way)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579616/send-value-of-submit-button-when-form-gets-posted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send value of submit button when form gets posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579616/send-value-of-submit-button-when-form-gets-posted)