# Ember.checkbox nested in action doesn't change value

Tags: ember.js

Template:

```
{{#each document in documents}}
    <div class="col-md-6" {{action "selectDocument" document}}>{{view Ember.Checkbox checked=document.isSelected}} {{document.name}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Controller:

```
App.IndexDocumentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
      actions: {
        selectDocument: function(document){
          document.set('isSelected', !document.get('isSelected'));
        }
      }
});
```

When I click on the div, the checkbox toggles 'checked' property. But when I click on the ckeckbox - nothing happens. What can be the reason?

**UPDATED**
Link to jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nuvocumuteto/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Can you add a bin showing the issue? You can create one here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Comment: I updated my post with link to jsbin. As you can see, nothing happens when you click a ckeckbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you click on  the checkbox 2 things happen.

1. the checkbox toggles the `isActive` property, then
2. the `selectRow` action is ran which again toggles the `isActive` property

So the `isActive` property ends up staying in the same state that it was.

In your case I would get rid of the action, wrap the checkbox in a `<label>` and set the label to `display: block`.

The template would look like

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li {{bind-attr class="item.isActive:active"}}><label>{{input type="checkbox" checked=item.isActive}}{{item.name}}</label></li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

and the css would look like

```
label {
 display: block; 
}
```

you would then be able to get rid of the `selectRow` action completely because clicking on the label will trigger the checkbox.

You can see a working bin here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nuvocumuteto/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that you are not following "The Ember Way" in two different ways here.

First, `Ember.Checkbox` is an internal Ember class (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Checkbox.html).  The recommended way to render a checkbox is to use the Handlebars input helpers (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/input-helpers/#toc_checkboxes).  This is just wrapping `Ember.Checkbox` anyway.

Second, if you want to update the value of `isSelected`, the "Ember Way" is to use **two-way** data bindings. Your code uses one-way data-binding when it reads `document.isSelected` and then tries to manually re-create the the data-binding in the other direction when the user clicks by manually writing a `selectDocument` action and calling it from an `{{action}}`.

Instead, simply bind the Ember Handlebars Input Helper directly to your value like this:

```
{{#each document in documents}}
    <div class="col-md-6">{{input type="checkbox" checked=document.isSelected}} {{document.name}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you, Josh. But I guess it won't be changed when I click on the div. I need to change isSelected when either div or checkbox is clicked. That's why I've created {{action}}

Comment: Ah, then you should just be able to add your `{{action}}` right back into the div!  Just make sure that you click EITHER your `{{action}}` or your checkbox, but not both.  By the way, if you're just trying to get the label to be clickable, you can use some HTML tricks to accomplish this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-an-html-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label