# HTML/CSS - <input> width

Tags: html, css, width

**Whilst there has been some input on this, the question of width control of `<input>` remains open.**

This problem relates to a WordPress site, but is reproducible in a very trivial form.

Context: I have a checkbox controlled, CSS nested heading/text toggle system. The checkbox is hidden and it all works well, except that I have no control over the checkbox width. Unless overridden it is about 14px wide - I want it full div width; I cannot achieve that. (The checkbox must sit over the following heading, hence position: absolute;)

**The actual checkbox cannot be resized, but it's clickable area can be: I am interested in the click area width.**

The WP page HTML is this (some bits truncated for brevity)

```
<div id="left-area">
<article id="post-399" class="et_pb_post ...">
    <h1></h1>
    <p class="post-meta"></p>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="nested-toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
```

Theme CSS styling on "left-area" sets the width at 712px. However, if the `<input>` is given width:100%; it comes out with a width of 968px, which is *not* that of the `<div id="left-area">` but in fact that of an outer  (styled by `div.container {...}` to give width = 968px).

The effect can be reproduced with the following minimal example

```
<div class="leftside">
  <input type="checkbox" checked><i></i>
  <h2>a Heading</h2>
</div>
```

with styling

```
div.leftside {width:900px;}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This was all done with Firefox (current version) and the minimal example checked at codepen.io.

I'm relatively new (again) to this; I have I done something stupid?

What's going wrong, and how can I set `<input>` to have the right width?

Thx!

PS One of FF or WP seems to add `</input>` after my `<input>`; technically that seems to be invalid HTML as it causes an error when validating at W3C but it doesn't seem to affect the rendering behaviour.

Comment: Hey, take a look of my new answer... It might be what you are looking for... Comment me for more ;)

Answer (score 0):

### css3 @media rule

You might also need to take a look at [CSS3 @media Rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

By running the snippet, clicking full page button and then resize the window you will see that the box become responsive in relation to the page width.

While the page has more than 500px width the div's width stay at 400px.

But when the page become lower than 500px the div's width become 100px.

Check if your css stylesheet has @media rule!!!

```css
#tricolore {
        background-color: green;
        width: 400px;
        height: 50px;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #tricolore {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="tricolore"></div>
```

---

### New Answer

As we said there was no way to resize the checkbox but you can resize the label of it.

We can use a div inside a label to give size to our label.

***Check the following snippet with my example:***

```css
#myDiv{
  width:550px;
  height:90px;
  background-color:red;
}

#myInput{
  /*
  display:none;
  */
}
```

```html
<label>
  <div id="myDiv">
    Text
   <input id="myInput" type="checkbox" name="something" value="something">      
    Text
  </div>
</label>
```

***And the snippet with your minimal example (Ignore the red background).***

```css
#myDiv{
  background-color:red;
}

#myInput{
  /*
  display:none;
  */
}

div.leftside {width:900px;}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <div class="leftside"id="myDiv">
   <input type="checkbox" checked><i></i>      
   <h2>a Heading</h2>
  </div>
</label>
```

---

### Old Answer

If you are trying to change the Box size i think it cannot be changed by changing the width attribute of the input. Is this what you are trying to do?

Or you want to set CheckBox near H2?

`<h2><label for="a">Header</label> <input type="checkbox" name="header" id="a" value="Header" checked></h2>`

Does this help?

https://jsfiddle.net/ysfbww7r/4/

Try this one also.

Do you need the Headings?

Comment: The actual checkbox square is fixed size, but its clickable extent depends on height and width. I need the click area to cover the heading whose content toggle it controls.

Comment: You want to use heading as click area?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Everything works great except with responsive design and without width control based on the parent div width I cant reliably stop the clickable area overflowing and intercepting clicks that should go to other things.

Comment: Without styled width your suggestion `<h2><label for="a">Header</label> <input type="checkbox" name="header" id="a" value="Header" checked></h2>` does nicely put a checkbox adjacent to the heading text but it is only 13x13px. With styled width % it's still not a % of the direct containing div width. Unfortunately.

Comment: Open this and click at the Header and see what hapens: https://jsfiddle.net/ysfbww7r/

Comment: Do you want to increase the box size? Can you make a draw of what you need?

Comment: Thx but I can still only click on the square boundary of the checkbox and not the extent of the element, which is what I need. Imagine a rectangle as high and wide as the heading that overlays the heading... that's the clickable area I would like. The thing that stops width working is `position:absolute;` if I could get the checkbox on the same line as the heading without it I could solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please draw it. I really want to help but i cannot imagine it. In my case the checkbox is near header. You want the checkbox in front of header but not near it?

Comment: Sorry, can't find a way to draw here. Imagine a long thin horizontal rectangle. The heading goes inside it. Where the checkbox goes I don't care, but it will probably be at the same vertical position. X for checkbox can be small but the whole rectangle should change the state of the checkbox, i.e. be clickable. It's a problem with checkboxes I think...

Comment: If you really want to help you should follow my minimal example, and go on from there: you have not sized your divs so the effect cannot show up.

Comment: I did follow your minimal example but your desciption is not so clear. I hope you get your answer.  :/

Comment: "*I* do not understand your description." - FTFY

Comment: What is FTFY? Did you find the answer you want?

Comment: FTFY = "Fixed that for you" (NB Google is your friend). I have an approach that I am testing based on the fiddle mentioned in the second answer. Not working yet. Thanks for asking :)

Comment: Oh, give me the fiddle link and tell me what you want to change. :)

Comment: Did you find an answer here?

Comment: Hmmm... yes, that does seem to work! Let me see how it works out in real life rather than the simple test case... adding nested label and div affects a number of CSS selectors so I have to refactor. Thx for the effort; more later I hope

Comment: Correction: I now note (missed it earlier) that your inner div (inside label) gives an explicit width. Given an explicit width this always works (as implied by my original question) the problem is that the page is responsive and that explicit widths at this level are not welcome. The issue is still where/why/how and how to make the clickable area dynamically resize. Why is it getting width from div.container (original question). Effort appreciated but, unless I have misunderstood your answer, it does not resolve the issue.

Comment: You might need an at media rule. Is your site changing its whole style when resizing the window? Or it is just changing its items width?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, Julian Moore is right with the clickable label...

here's an updated fiddle (originally posted related to the following entry [How to create an HTML checkbox with a clickable label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-an-html-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label))

http://jsfiddle.net/qYZFJ/1283/

HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" /><h2>Option 1</h2></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" /><h2>Option 2</h2></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" /><h2>Option 3</h2></label>
```

CSS:

```
label {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 margin:0 0 10px;
 display:block; 
}
label:hover {
 background:#eee;
 cursor:pointer;
}
label>input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
label>input[type=checkbox] + h2 {
    background: #f2d4d4;
    display: block;
    padding:10px;
}
label>input[type=checkbox]:checked + h2 {
    background: red;
}
```

EDIT:

here is another fiddle showing a pure css/html text-toggle system...

http://jsfiddle.net/qjLguro9/2/

HTML:

```
  <label class="toggle" for="chkShow1">Show first element</label>
  <input id="chkShow1" type="checkbox">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum ... however, this is the first content</div>

  <label class="toggle" for="chkShow2">Show second element</label>
  <input id="chkShow2" type="checkbox">
  <div>This is the second content ;)</div>
```

CSS:

```
.toggle{
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.toggle + input{
  display:none;
}
.toggle + input + *{
  display:none;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.toggle+ input:checked + *{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: I think the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qYZFJ/ is all I need, thanks. The label autosizes to the div. I just need to turn headings into labels...

Comment: Doesn't work. Will put up with strange widths for now.