# clickable label checkboxes with HTML Helper

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I need to do clickable checkboxes using `HTML helpers`. I've written this code without any problems:

```
var checkBox = "<label><input type='checkbox' name='vacationTypes' data-id = '"
    + data.checkboxList[i].Id + "' value = '"
    + data.checkboxList[i].Id
    + "' id='Edit-document-checkbox"
    + data.checkboxList[i].Id + "'/>"
    + data.checkboxList[i].Type + "</label>" + "<br/>";
```

All works fine. But now I need to do like this with `html helpers`. This is my code:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Id)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].IsSelected) @Html.LabelFor(x=>x[i].IsSelected, Model[i].Type)
    </div>
}
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: Do you simply need the `<label>` tag to wrap around your checkbox? If so there's nothing to be gained by using `Html.LabelFor` in this case, just do something like `<label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].IsSelected)@Model[i].Type</label>`.

Comment: I need to do clickable checkbox lables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-an-html-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label

Comment: I assume by clickable you mean having the checkbox react to the label text being clicked? Wrapping the checkbox with the label does exactly that...

Comment: @Dom that should be an answer not a comment