# How to align a label with checkbox

Tags: html, css

```css
span{
text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="type"><span>Excessive Reinforcement</span><br>
```

[I want to align the label for excessive reinforcement checkbox like image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdwgj.png)

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U3nO.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: add your code you try

Comment: Please [learn to love actual label elements](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-an-html-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label

Comment: You could wrap your checkbox inside a label element with the text inside.

Comment: From next question onwards, try to be more descriptive. Nobody knows, what is your image 2 here. In Stack Overflow, while asking question there is option to insert inline images as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
span {
  text-align: justify;
}
.make-table {
  display: table-cell;
  /* make it behave like table-cell. so that they fall beside each other. */
}
```

```html
<div class="any-class">
  <label><span class="make-table"><input type="checkbox" name="type"></span>
    <span class="make-table">Excessive<br> Reinforcement</span>
  </label>
</div>

<hr>
<div style="color:red">Wrap it inside any-class and align as you want.
  <br>I added LABEL tag, so that, even if your user clicks on the text, the checkbox will work.</div>
```

Make this simple change!

Comment: @GowmathiBaskaran If it worked for you, you can mark this post as correct Answer !

Answer (score 2):

First of all use `<label>` instead of `<span>`.

If we use bootstrap we generally manage this with classes but here if we talk about custom css this can be a solution.

```css
label{
   text-align: justify;
   float: left;
   line-height: 20px;
}
input{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="type"><label for="check">Excessive<br>Reinforcement</label><br>
```

> Above i added `id` in checkbox and `for` in label so that checkbox will be selected on click of label also.

**If you can change the HTML**

The best and new method to use checkbox is

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="type">Excessive Reinforcement</label>
```

Comment: check my code in snippet its fine in 2 lines...please make a fiddle of your code

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it:

```
<label for="type-1">
   <input id="type=1" type="checkbox" name="type"> Excessive Reinforcement
</label><br>
```

When using input elements, you should always provide a label with the for attribute assigned the id of the input element. And also make sure the input element ids are unique.