# How to check or uncheck checkboxes by clicking on text instead of checkbox itself?

Tags: html, checkbox

I have seen it on several webpages (cannot recall where exactly atm) where I am able to check or uncheck checkboxes by clicking on the text in front of the checkbox. I know how to do it in JavaScript (create a span with onclick()) , but I want to know if there is any way I can do it without JavaScript.

Comment: You are looking for the [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) tag.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-an-html-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality using `label` tag as given below.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="option">

<label for="option">Select this option</label>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is what I was looking for. Sometimes even little straightforward things get out of mind and are hard to recall :A (y)

Comment: @niyasc Note that `label` is a tag and not a class.