# Adding text field inside of checkbox

Tags: php

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?echo $row->field_id?>" <?echo $checked?> > <?php echo $row->field_display_name;?><br/>
```

Here `$row->field_id` is my field name,how can I change it to text field. I wanted to show it as a text field.

Comment: you can't have a text field inside a checkbox

Comment: It is unclear, what you ask. The `value="<?echo $row->field_id?>"` property you have in your input element is not visible, hidden. What sense is there in a hidden "text field"? I assume you want something else: a checkbox and a text field next to each other that somehow correspond?

Comment: Actually i want a text field next to that of checkbox..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-an-html-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label