# Svelte - {#each} {/each} generating unique ids in an object passed down to component

Tags: svelte

I want to generate a list of custom components , composed of an input field and a few checkboxes:

```
<script>
const messages = [
 { id: "2fzae4", text: "aaaaa"},
 { id: "456ndr", text: "bbbbb"}

];

const tags = [
  { id: "01", label: "Twitter"},
  { id: "02", label: "Instagram"}
];
</script>

<ul>
{#each messages as msg (msg.id)}
  <li>
      <Ainput textField={msg.text} {tags}/>
  </li>
{/each}
</ul>
```

```
// This is a part of the <Ainput> component 

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" bind:value={textField}/>
  <Tag {tags} />
</div>
```

```
// Tag component, a set of checkboxes
<script>
 export let tags;
</script>

<div>
 {#each tags as tag (tag.id)}
 <div>
   <checkbox id="{tags.id}"/>
   <label for="{tags.id}">{tags.label}</label>
 </div>
 {/each}
</div>
```

I need to pass down unique tag.id values in the array 'tags' on every iteration to make checkboxes work, but how to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64928001/svelte-associate-label-and-input-in-a-reusabe-way has better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that. Check out [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6293626/1871033). You can just put the `<input>` *inside* the `<label>`, then no `id`/`for` is needed:

```
<div>
 {#each tags as tag (tag.id)}
   <div>
     <label>
      <input type="checkbox"/>
      {tags.label}
     </label>
   </div>
 {/each}
</div>
```

Working demo:

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    Click me, please!
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    No, click me instead!
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, yes, this of course would be fine, but styling does not work when there are no ids assigned.

Comment: I don't understand. Why?

Comment: Also, you could just assign random IDs to the `tag` elements in the array and use those afterwards.

Comment: @CherryT: Oh, sorry, my styles use "+" combinator, so they got messed up when <input> when inside <label>, will fix it; thank you very much, your answer is correct, very helpful. And how exactly could I modify tags.id while it is used inside {#each}{/each}?

Comment: Ah; in that case I think just reordering your style selector would fix it, and it'd probably be the easiest and cleanest way to do it without IDs :)

Comment: This is not a complete answer, sometimes you may want a label and input to be in different places, and [explicit for=id labels are better for accessibility tools](https://css-tricks.com/html-inputs-and-labels-a-love-story/#how-to-pair-a-label-and-an-input).

Comment: Also accessibility-wise, ARIA attributes often need to refer to other elements by their IDs. For instance, ` aria-controls` or `aria-labelledby`.

Comment: Another use case that is not answered by this is the `name` attribute on `input[type="radio"]`.