# Svelte: Associate label and input in a reusabe way

Tags: html, dom, svelte, svelte-3

I'm building a Svelte input component which should be usable multible times on the same page.

```
<div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
        <input bind:value>
        <!-- some more elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Trying to associate label and input I have the following problem:

- I can't use implicit association by changing the outer `<div>` to `<label>`, since the input is not a direct child.
- I can't use the labels `for` attribute, since reusing the element would create mutible identical ids.

Is there a way to create component instance unique ids (pre- or postfixed) in Svelte or is there another solution to this problem.

---

Or is the best solution to manually set a random string as id?

```
<script>
    const id = random_string();
    /* ... */
</script>

<div>
    <label for={id}>{label}</label>
    <div>
        <input {id} bind:value>
        <!-- some more elements -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could define a counter in module context and then use it to create unique IDs

**Input.svelte**

```
<script context="module">
    let counter = 0
</script>
<script>
        export let label
        let value
        let eltId = 'input_'+ counter++
</script>

<div>
    <label for={eltId}>{label}</label>
    <div>
        <input id={eltId} bind:value>
    </div>
</div>
```

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
    import Input from './Input.svelte'
</script>

<Input label='Select Country' />
<Input label='Select Country' />
<Input label='Select Country' />
```

See [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5e0255a5fa7b4fb59e7ef8e83c7e4a82?version=3.32.0)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just define a unique name for the input since your need one? You could then just have a component like:

**Input.svelte**

```html
<script>
    export let name
    export let label
    let value
        
    const getInputId = () => {
        return `input_${name}`
    }
</script>

<div>
    <label for={getInputId()}>{label}</label>
    <div>
        <input id={getInputId()} bind:value>
    </div>
</div>
```

And use it like:

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import Input from './Input.svelte'
</script>

<Input name='country' label='Select Country' />
```

Checkout the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4a090f8e5cfe4a6c9c88f4fbad042f52?version=3).

Comment: This is not possible, if the top form itself has to be reusable. And why should the compnent **need** a name?

Comment: This is a footgun, you're gonna accidentally collide two names and then clicking some label will toggle a checkbox on the other side of the page