# How to create a checkbox with a clickable label that trigger seperate event and not checkout/in the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, onclick, dom-events

There is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-a-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label) about the clickable label,
what I'm trying to find out how to make clickable labels that are not check-in/out the
checkbox, but trigger separate event which effecting the checkbox.

This is the div with the checkboxes and labels:

```
  <div class="containerSelectBox" id="multi_select">
                <input type="checkbox" /><label id="a1"> This is checkbox </label><br/>
                <input type="checkbox" /><label id="a2"> This is checkbox </label><br/>
                <input type="checkbox" /><label id="a3"> This is checkbox </label><br/>
                <input type="checkbox" /><label  id="a4"> This is checkbox </label><br/>
                <input type="checkbox" /><label  id="a5"> This is checkbox </label><br/>

            </div>
```

What I like to find is when clicking on each label it will for example alert the id of this label.
I can't just write `onclick` on each label I need to attach dynamically to the `onclick` event trigger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! After 12 years at SO it is time to visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by _not check-in/out the
Checkbox_

Comment: i mean that the label will fire an event when clicked and not affect the checkbox near the lable ( i guess it can be div or something also )

Comment: So you mean `but trigger separate event WITHOUT effecting the checkbox`

Comment: Just don't make it a label or remove the `for` or don't wrap it around the checkbox. What is the usecase here?

Comment: use case: when clicking the label it will open a new window, the checkbox will be only indicator that say this row is selected

Comment: So have `<input type="checkbox"> <a href="newpage.html" target="_blank">Open in new page</a>`

Comment: @mplungjan no.. not that simple it is opening javascript dynamic windows on click

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and explain what you expect to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 const labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");
 labels.foreach(label => {
 label.addEventListener("click", event => {

       // PUT HERE WHAT YOU WANT TO DO WHEN THE 
      LABEL IS CLICKED
    })
 })
```