# React Checkbox could not have active state while clicking the label besides

Tags: css, reactjs

[The checkbox could not be in active state when clicking the label on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKmh3.png)

```
const [checkTandC, setCheckTandC] = useState(false)

<div className="form-check-wrapper">
    <div className="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id='agreement' className='form-check-input' onChange={() => setCheckTandC(!checkTandC)} />
        <label htmlFor="agreement" className='form-check-label'>Are you agree to Clicon <span>Terms of Condition</span> and <span>Privacy Policy</span>.</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**styles.css**

```
.account-wrapper-form .form-check-input:checked{
    background-color: #FA8232;
    border-color: #FA8232;
}
.account-wrapper-form .form-check-input:checked[type=checkbox]{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='%23fff' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='3' d='M6 10l3 3l6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    /* font-size: 20px; */
}
.form-check-input:active{
  filter: brightness(90%);
}
```

I would like to have the checkbox be in active state while clicking the label on the right side but it only works when clicking on the checkbox. May I ask how to have the checkbox have the brightness changed when clicking on checkbox and also clicking the label?

Comment: You need to remove the default styles - add `appearance: none` to the checkbox and add Yours height and width to the checked state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a checkbox with a clickable label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-a-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label)

Comment: Even I wrapped the input into label div it still could not help

Comment: @ProgrammingMERN As far I can see, the checkbox do get opacity changed when you hold mouse on the label. Not sure what else are you facing?

Comment: When I mouse over the checkbox it does not have any effects

Comment: @ProgrammingMERN I split the line in label using <br> into three lines. And in onChange I display a message in the console. When I release the button on any of the three lines or checkbox, I see a message. I also see that at the moment of pressing the brightness visually changes(this works as long as the button is pressed). Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I expect when clicking the label the brightness of button will change but only taking effect when clicking on the button

Comment: With your code I can click on the label to make the checkbox active and vice versa.